# Is there a way to produce back-to-back haptic vibrations?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm able to easily produce vibration with `HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();`, but I wanted to chain the vibrations to give two thumps back to back, doing

```
HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
```

Seems to still only produce one thump.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try adding a delay between the two using `Future.delayed`? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html

Comment: @mmcdon20 It does work, but seems hacky as the length of the vibration is different between platforms

Comment: Did you come up with anything better?  I'm also running into this problem.  Sleep function also seems to work, but also is a hack.  See also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675864